# Python removing multiple files using map and os.remove

Tags: python, operating-system, glob

I am trying to remove multiple files using this method:

```py
map(os.remove, glob.glob("*.pdf"))
```

I am getting a list of files with pdf extension but this does not remove any files.

My solution was to wrap this map with `list()`.

Any other solution that does not require using list or something?

Comment: Just use a for-loop, don't use `map` for side-effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for i in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
    os.remove(i)
```

The reason why `map(...)` doesn't work by itself is that `map(...)` will return a generator and it will only evaluate the expressions once the items are actually accessed from the generator.

Furthermore, the point of `map(...)` is to group the results of the expressions returned by the function that is called on every item, but that doesn't really make sense here since `os.remove(...)` doesn't really return anything (or, in other words, returns `None`), so since assembling a list of `None`s doesn't really serve much purpose (you're throwing it out right away anyways), using a `for` loop is a more appropriate way to approach this task.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to find another way from a for loop. Could you think about something else that does not require a loop?
Or you say this is the only way?

Comment: @ShayHa The `for` loop is the *right* way to do it. It is simple, straightforward, clear. Why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: Just thinking, trying to figure out more ways. But if it is the right way I guess there is no need to search for another one.

Comment: Still, your init comment for list(map(os.remove, files2delete)) is quite functioning, elegant & functional (style). Why aren't you satisfied?

Comment: @Lopofsky This might be a nitpick, but I'm not sure I'd call `map(os.remove, ...)` functional style, since `os.remove` is being called *for its side effect*, which is not really what you'd have in a proper or pure functional paradigm... And perhaps that's really the point here: `map()` is great with actually pure functions, where the lazy evaluation is working for you. And not really suitable for side effects, since you need workarounds or gimmicks such as producing a list that you won't use for it to actually do what you want.